# In a bash script, how to use a variable inside a command and assign to a new variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, hashsum

I'm trying to store the MD5 of a variable into another variable. Between backticks and the more modern `()` notation, I cannot figure out how to assign the value of a variable run through a command to another variable. Sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash
backup_dir=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
hashed=$( ${backup_dir} | md5)
```

Here, the `hashed` variable doesn't work, it takes the literal string `backup_dir` and hashes that. So the hash is always the same. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `hashed=$( echo ${backup_dir} | md5)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting `md5` to read the value of the `backup_dir` variable and return its MD5 hash sum.

The command pipeline

```
${backup_dir} | md5
```

would try to run `$backup_dir` as a command, piping its output to `md5`.  I would expect a "command not found" error from this, along with the MD5 hash of the empty string (`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`) in `$hashed`.

Instead, you would need to use something like

```
printf '%s' "$backup_dir" | md5
```

to give `md5` the value on its standard input stream.

You could also use `echo "$backup_dir" | md5` or `md5 <<<"$backup_dir"`, but note that this adds a newline to the end of the value of `$backup_dir` which would alter the hash.

If `md5` is the `md5` utility commonly found on BSD and BSD-like systems (e.g. macOS), then you should use

```
md5 -q -s "$backup_dir"
```

The `-s` option takes a string as its argument, and `-q` causes `md5` to only print out the hash of that string and nothing else.

Summary:

```
#!/bin/bash
backup_dir=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
hashed=$(md5 -q -s "$backup_dir")
```

Comment: This works and looks clean. Thank you for the patient explanation!